# ValueError: Names should be list-like for a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

How to avoid the error after pivoting dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['one', 'one', 'one'],
               'baz': [1, 2, 3],
               'zoo': ['x', 'y', 'z']})

df1 = df.pivot('baz', 'zoo', 'foo')
column = (1, 2)
df1[column] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use loc or iloc to set values. For example, the last line in your code could be:

```
df1.iloc[:,column] = np.nan
```

to set columns 1, and 2 to np.nan or:

```
df1.loc[column,:] = np.nan
```

to set the rows labelled 1 and 2 to np.nan

Comment: Thanks)) still I get an error...for column name I try to use tuple : ( 1,2)                
        pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
df1 = df.pivot('baz', 'zoo', 'foo')
```

is equivalent to:

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='baz', columns='zoo', values='foo')
```

So your index is the 'baz' column.  You're trying to index

```
df1[(1,2)]
```

but that's a tuple index.  Your index is really an integer.  So here are some examples that would work:

```
df1[1] 
df1[2]
```

would work.